# PHP: Curl can't grab a text-only page on my own site

Tags: php, curl

I'm attempting to use curl inside php to grab a page from my own web server.  The page is pretty simple, just has some plain text output.  However, it returns 'null'.  I can successfully retrieve other pages on other domains and on my own server with it.  I can see it in the browser just fine, and I can grab it with command line wget just fine, it's just that when I try to grab that one particular page with curl, it simply comes up null.  We can't use file_get_contents because our host has it disabled.

Why in the world would this be different behavior be happening?

Comment: Can you put up a link to the page?

Comment: And have you tried curl_error()? http://de2.php.net/curl_error

Comment: @Pekka: Unfortunately, no I can't share the page with the public.  And curl_error() doesn't cough anything up.  I was hoping that 'site showing up fine in a browser, not showing up with curl' in and of itself was indicative of something...

Comment: can post your code? it makes things much easier for people to help when they can see it. :)

Comment: What is the header response for request? Make sure to enable headers to be part of response output. `CURLOPT_HEADER` is the option.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue.  I was putting my url someplace that was not in curl_init(), and that place was truncating the query string.  Once I moved it back to curl_init, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try [setting](http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2007/01/29/how-to-set-the-curl-user-agent-string-with-php/) curl's user agent. Sometimes hosts will block "bots" by blocking things like wget or curl - but usually they do this just by examining the user agent.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the output of `curl_error()` and also take a look at your logfiles for the http server.